# Math.round() wrong calculation in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, rounding

Can anyone explain this?

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Double precision numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: NAFPQ: not another floating point question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.Round(x:Number) rounds x to the nearest integer value. In your case 28 is the nearest integer value for 28.499999999999996. So here the behavior is correct. What is weird is that 0.285 * 100 is not 28.5, but that is a consequence of the precision of the Number class in as3. Here is a little more information about this and a possible solution:

[Innacurate math results](http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/flashactionscript-innaccurate-math-results/)

Also you can see this SO question:

[Very strange number operation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154651/flex-as3-very-strange-simple-number-operation-issue)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Round is doing the correct thing. 0.285 cannot be exactly represented as a binary floating point value. As you see, when multiplied by 100 it approximates to 28.4999999... which is less than 28.5, so the value is rounded down.